# Clear dnsmasq cache without restarting the service

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, cache, dnsmasq

I have cache enabled in my `dnsmasq`, because it is *fast*.

In some situations (for example, with VPN off), `dnsmasq` caches wrong results. I want a quick way to clean the cache (when I connect to the VPN for example). Restarting the service works, but it is slow (takes some seconds). I have tried sending `SIGHUP`, which as expected reloads the configuration, but does not flush the cache.

Is there a way to flush the `dnsmasq` cache without restarting it?

Answer (score 5):

If you add the following to your dnsmasq.conf this will allow you to clear the cache on a reload rather than a restart.

```
clear-on-reload
```

Then we you want to clear the cache you trigger a reload..

```
pkill -HUP dnsmasq
```

You can check the contents (dumps stats to the log) of the cache with

```
pkill -USR1 dnsmasq
```

Comment: Strange, I tried it but the cache is not cleared after HUP ...

Comment: Does the SIGUSR1 trigger the stats dump to logs?

Comment: Yes. `HUP` triggers reload, and `SIGUSR1` dumps the cache, which is not empty, even after making sure that the `clear-on-reload` directive is enabled in the config.

Comment: Weird one I use SIGHUP on my custom AP's and it works..    Now last when you restart dnsmasqd are there any warning or errors when it loads the config file?.

Comment: Not really. I even made sure of that by forcing errors to see the difference between a good config and a bad config

Comment: What version of dnsmasq do you have?     {dnsmasq -v}

Comment: Ah it seems that SIGHUP doesn't clear the cache if you are using --hostsdir/--dhcp-hostsdir in that instance it in effect doesn't have a cache as the information is in the specified directory.    However it will automatic adjust if the contents of the directory change.